# WP SQL add meta_key with an empty meta_value to all users

Tags: mysql, wordpress

For a project we created a new_user_meta table that has new information and updates to the WP user_meta table. The problem is, the new_user_meta has meta key's that the old doesn't have and it won't update to them as they won't exist.

How can I add a new meta_key with an empty meta_value to an array of user ID's?

Example:
meta_key (education) meta_value (empty value) user_id (105, 251, 364) ?

I want to use an SQL query for this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an solution..

First I fetched all ID's of the users I want to put in the meta_key and meta_value in.

Then I used the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta`(`user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (ID148 , 'somekey','somevalue'), (ID156 , 'somekey','somevalue'),
```

I changed the somekey (meta_key) and somevalue (meta_value) and repeated it for every meta_key I needed to insert.